# Show array on template angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class with an array imported from another file, the array its correctly improted but is not shown at the template

the array definition

```
let list = [
  {nombre :"primero"},
  {nombre :"segundo"},
  {nombre :"tercero"}
];

export {list};
```

The class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Clock } from '../classes/clock';
import { ClockFactory } from '../classes/clockFactory';
import { list } from '../data/data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crono',
  templateUrl: './crono.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crono.component.css']
})
export class CronoComponent implements OnInit {


  public lapses:Array<Clock>=[];
  private factory:ClockFactory;
  private persona ={ nombre:'Nombre'};
  private lista = list;

  constructor(factory:ClockFactory) {
    console.log('constructor Crono');
    console.log(this.lista);
    this.factory = factory;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and the template

```
<div>
  <p *ngFor="let element of list">{{element.nombre}}</p>
</div>
```

This code could not make sense but its only for test purposes,I'm learning angular2

Comment: list is an object with an attribute named list, which is a array. It's not an array (as your console.log should show, and as the error you should get in the console explains. Also, your property is named lista, not list. And it should be public, not private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exporting a list which is actually an object not an array replace your list export with this one

```
 export const list = [
  {nombre :"primero"},
  {nombre :"segundo"},
  {nombre :"tercero"}
 ];
```

and in your component  you've created `list` property but uterating over `list` rename list property `list` with this

```
 private list = list;
```